# Spark 2.4 FileAlreadyExist Error while writing a dataframe to hdfs in parquet format - DynamicOverwrite=TRUE

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am getting a FileAreadyExist Error while writing a huge spark dataframe (Spark 2.4) to hdfs in parquet format to load to Impala table.
Its something similar to this issue
[FileAlreadyExistsException while using Spark insertInto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948379/filealreadyexistsexception-while-using-spark-insertinto)

Now, i know that this issue is fixed in Spark 3.1.0 and so on, but i cannot simply migrate and all our systems to spark 3.1.0 and consider it as a fix for me.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue in Spark 2.4 somehow ?

Thanks